# Any polynomial has a finite number of solutions – well, any? --- The non-commutative case

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, noncommutative-algebra

First, some teasers; then, at the end of 2), the question.

The above statement holds for polynomials which are normalised (the leading coefficient is one, or a unit) and defined in rings $R[X]$ where $R$ a commutative ring.

1) If your polynomial is not normalised then there can be an infinity of solutions, of course. Take, for instance, $P_\phi=\phi X$ over the ring $R=\mathbb F_2^E$ of functions on some infinite set $E$ into the ring $\mathbb F_2 = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and let $\phi \in R$ be such that $\phi^{-1}(\{1\})$ is finite. 
Note however, that even for those $\phi$ for which $P_\phi$ has only finitely many solutions, it can be more than $1 = \deg P_\phi$, even arbitrarily many, if $\phi$ is chosen in an appropriate way.

2) If $R$ is not commutative, $R[X]$ can still be naturally endowed with the structure of a ring. However, evaluation is not necessarily a homomorphism anymore. In this case, are there normalised polynomials with an infinity of solutions? Matrix rings, perhaps? I am looking for a simple and intuitive example. Someone here who knows one?

So long, K.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934479/stuff-which-squares-to-1-in-the-quaternions-thinking-geometrically

Comment: Thanks for the comment that the question already has an answer in "Why are the solutions of polynomial equations so unconstrained over the quaternions?". This answers the question completely.